# Some data missing while process with Parallel Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, console-application

I write some code below :

```
_concurentModels = new ConcurrentQueue<ScanOutletBarcodeModel>();
models.ToList().ForEach(m => _concurentModels.Enqueue(m));
Parallel.Invoke(ProcessInParalel);

private void ProcessInParalel()
{
    Action[] actions;

    if (_concurentModels.Count > 0)
    {
        actions = new Action[GlobalVariable.ProcessorCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < GlobalVariable.ProcessorCount; i++)
        {
            actions[i] = (ThreadProcess);
        }

        Parallel.Invoke(actions);
    }

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

private void ThreadProcess()
{
   while (_concurentModels.TryDequeue(out model))
   {
       //proceed model
   } 
}
```

when i set `GlobalVariable.ProcessorCount` = 16, the process is running correctly (all list of model processed) but if i increase processor count become above 20, some record of model seems missing and not processed. it's weird in my mind, Is increasing the thread makes some data lost?

the reason that i increase processor count is because performance issue. Is anything wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Comment: What type is `_concurrentModels`?

Comment: _concurentModels = new ConcurrentQueue<ScanOutletBarcodeModel>();

Comment: What do you mean by "missing"? Where does the output of those actions go to?

Comment: for example the models contain 1000 records, i print it into text file and then only 999 appear, missing one record

Comment: Well, there might be a concurrency issue in regards to writing to a file in parallel, which is probably not thread-safe. What happens when you print to a console?